# Open jQuery tabs with URL

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a page with tabs on it that you this jQuery script

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/

I would like to be able to make the tab 3 be the first one open when a user goes to the URL http://mysite.com/about.php#tab3

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to example you can modifi it in this way:

```
$(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    //On Click Event (left standart)
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });


    // here we are looking for our tab header
    hash = window.location.hash;
    elements = $('a[href="' + hash + '"]');
    if (elements.length === 0) {
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    } else {
        elements.click();
    }
});
```

[Working example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6Nu2/6/). Be careful - hash is hardcoded there, because I don't know how to pass it to test frame :(

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test this, but you should be able to get the hash from the url with:

```
var hash= window.location.hash;
```

And then grabbing the link element with the requested hash, and emulating a click on it

```
$("a[href='"+hash+"']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could make that happen. You will need some code to grab the url and trigger the proper tab though.

Or you could check out Jquery Tools Tabs (http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/)
or Jquery UI tabs (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Both of these have that functionality (and a ton of other options) already built in.